# Reading a line from the clipboard in vb.net not matching text

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read from the clipboard and place in an array.  I want to validate the first line as the text: "Client Code " 
I fill the array with:

```
 tbClipBoardContents.Text = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()
 For Each strLine As String In tbClipBoardContents.Lines
            arrClipBoard.Add(strLine.ToString)
 Next
```

When I give a variable the value of the first array entry it appears correct = "Client Code " in Visual Studio debugging.

```
Dim test As String = Trim(arrClipBoard(0).ToString)
```

However when I check using the "IF" statement it tells me it is not correct??

```
If test = "Client Code " Then
    MsgBox("Correct Clipboard Structure")
Else
    MsgBox("Not a Valid Clipboard Structure: " & Trim(arrClipBoard(0).ToString))  ' ** Fires this response.
End If
```

What is doing my head in is that if I copy the value of test from VS debugger and paste it in the if statement it looks like "Client Code " but this time the if statement fires the correct response.
I have tried it by filling the textbox (tbClipBoardContents) using:

```
tbClipBoardContents.text.split(New [Char]() {CChar(vbCrLf)})
and
tbClipBoardContents.text.split(newvbline)
```

with the same results.

So does this mean the true value from the clipboard for the line "Client Code " also carries some hidden characters?  Any help is appreciated.

Brad

P.S. I have found that if I test the value of Mid(test,1,11) then I will get the desired result, so this is a workaround but would be interested to know what the 12th character is?  Perhaps it is the "CChar(vbCrLf)"

Comment: The `Trim` will have removed the trailing space from "Client Code ".

Comment: I would have thought so also, however when viewing in VS Debug the value for test.Length is 12 which includes middle and trailing space?  But even if I test the value of "test" against the full 12 chars (ie including middle and trailing spaces it still does not accept the match?  If I test the value of Mid(test,1,11) = "Client Code" then it works?

Comment: `MsgBox(AscW(test.Last()))` will show you the character code of the last character. Space is 32; "e" is 101. [`String.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8) also removes CR and LF characters.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Morton this told me that the trailing character was 160 which apparently is sometimes instead of 32.

Answer (score 0):

As  per my observation Trim will have removed the spaces. and you should change the condition to "ClientCode".

Comment: Thank you nirav gandhi, and I thought it would also remove the leading & trailing spaces, however this is not the case.  I am thinking there is some other "unprintable" character at the end.  Brad

Answer (score 0):

The final solution that worked for me was to find the trailing space using Andrew Morton's method above then

```
 arrClipBoard.Add(Trim(Regex.Replace(strLine.ToString, Convert.ToChar(160), "")))
```

which effectively converted the char(160) to "".